# Fonts not displaying on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, fonts

Hope someone can assist with an issue I have been having all week. It seems that 1 out of my 4 font-faces are causing issues on my clients Mac. This really stumps me as the three other fonts work fine on Macs and this 4th font type () doesn't even fall back to the subsequent fonts I provided as back-up.

You can see the sites here (http://jsfiddle.net/kLL62/) there is also the actual URL of the hosted site in the first line of the CSS if you would like to see the issue live. Basically the 'ChevinBold' font is used in three locations:

1. There is an animation that comes up if your screen is wider than 1366 pixels - the last frame should be text (this text doesnt render on Macs).
2. On the Team Page, there should be the team members names in the yellow boxes above each profile
3. On the Contact Us Page, up the mailto: link for the email address, it should say 'Contact Us'

The offending CSS is exactly the same as the other three fonts that work just fine:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'ChevinBold';
src: url('../fonts/chevin-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/chevin-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/chevin-bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/chevin-bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/chevin-bold.svg#ChevinBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Byron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like the font file might be corrupted - try converting it again and Font Squirrel is the only provider that suggests the file is corrupted and I cant think of any other reasons this could be happening.

Comment: Problem solved - corrupted font file. Had the designer rebuild it and it's working great now!